# How can i replace the first instance of an integer in a string list in java?

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting, arraylist

```
 public void replaceFirst(int oldVal, int newVal){
      // Convert int array to integer list
      List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      for (int i : list)  intList.add(i);
      // Convert integer list to string list
      List<String> strList = intList.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());

      // find first occurance of a value in string list and replace with new value
      for (int i = 0; i < strList.size(); i++) {
        String replacedStr = strList.get(i).replaceFirst(Integer.toString(oldVal), Integer.toString(newVal));
    strList.set(i, replacedStr);
      }

}
```

I need to make a method which takes 2 parameters

*oldVal* - **first occurrence of integer value in the array to replace**.
*newVal* - **integer value replacing the old value**.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Is the code you pasted your current solution? Where does "list" come from? Do you have a test case?

Comment: list is the name of the int array i am converting to a list to make the method functional. After running this method in the main class the array values are retained to their original values and never change.

Comment: @DonavanHamels You are changing `strList` instead of `list`, so the expected behaviour is for `list` not to change.

Answer (score 1):

You mutate `strList` correctly but you never use it for anything. You simply set the values and then let it go out of scope.